# powershell script to list folders which do not contain a recent backup file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I need a PowerShell script to check for recent backup files and list any folders which DO NOT contain a recent backup. I need to search a folder and it's sub folders and only return the folder names which DO NOT contain a file `*.cfg` less than 30 days old.

So far I have `(c:\backups contains multiple subfolders which contain the *.cfg files)` -

```
gci C:\backups\ -Recurse -Include *.cfg |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}| Select Directory -Unique
```

This works but in reverse, it lists folder which do have the file. I need to reverse the logic and list folders which do not contain the file. I have tried several options with -not and ! in the where-object but nothing works. Would be great if someone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've already build an exclusion list...

```
$foldersWhichHaveBackups = Get-Content C:\backups\ -Recurse -Include *.cfg |
                                Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |
                                Select Directory -Unique

$allFolders = Get-Content C:\backups\ -Recurse | Select Directory -Unique

$FoldersWhichDoNotHaveBackups = $allFolders |
                                Where-object {$_.Directory -notin $foldersWhichHaveBackups.Directory}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. Didn't have too much success with your suggestion but it certainly set me on the right track thanks

Comment: @SHughes. No problem. Just edited as realized you're explicitly selecting `Directory` so `FullName` will not be a valid property. Let me know if that does/doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

after some input from gms0ulman, thanks again, I came up with the following -

$foldersWhichHaveBackups = gci 'C:\backup' -Recurse -Include *.cfg | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | Select Directory -Unique

$allFolders = gci 'C:\backup' -Directory | Select FullName

Compare-Object $allfolders.FullName $foldersWhichHaveBackups.Directory | select -ExpandProperty inputobject

if anyone can suggest a better way I am very keen to learn.